# Работа со Spring

Tags: java, spring

Начав разбираться со Spring framework, решил написать тестовую программу.

```
package Spring;

public class Hello {
private String s;

public Hello(String str){
    s = str;
}

public void sayHi(){
    System.out.println(s);
}

public static void main(String []args)
{
    ClassPathXmlApplicationContext ac = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(new String[] {"config.xml"});//показываем Spring где лежит файл конфигурации
    Hello h = (Hello) ac.getBean("hello");//указываем id нашего bean-а
    h.sayHi();
}
}
```

И содержимое xml файла в папке проекта bin:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"    
xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans   
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

<bean id="hello" class="main.Hello">
<constructor-arg value="Hi!!!"/>
</bean>
</beans>
```

Eclipse ругается на `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext`. Прошу вас указать на ошибку и показать пути её решения. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Это _весь_ код программы? Импорты у вас есть? Если есть, то импортируете ли вы `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext`? И если импортируете, то подключена ли к проекту библиотека, содержащая этот класс?

Comment: И ещё: в конфигурации вы указываете класс `main.Hello`, в то время как ваш пакет называется `Spring`, тогда полное имя класса - `Spring.Hello`.

Comment: Нет не импортирую, и не подключена. В тестовом уроке об этом не слова.

Comment: Тогда выкиньте этот тестовый урок на помойку и почитайте что-нибудь более близкое к реальности, например, это: http://www.mkyong.com/spring/quick-start-maven-spring-example/

Comment: Благодарю за ответ!

Comment: Не за что. Когда я давал вам ссылку, я немного поторопился, и привёл ссылку на урок по Spring 2.x. Всё, что в нём описано, применимо и в более поздних версиях Spring (текущая - 4.2.2), просто в более поздних версиях появлябтся более простые механизмы инициализации и привязки бинов (чрез аннотации или Java-конфигурации). Можете почитать про это на [сайте проекта](http://projects.spring.io/spring-framework/) или [здесь](http://spring-projects.ru/).

Comment: @fori1ton Пожалуйста, опубликуйте ваши комментарии в виде ответа.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, готово

Answer (score 1):

Проблема этого кода - отсутствие импорта класса `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext`, который вы используете в программе. Если добавить после объявления пакета строку

```
org.springframework.context.support.Class ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;
```

программа станет корректной. Однако, для того чтобы она скомпилировалась, необходимо, чтобы к проекту была подключена библиотека, содержащая этот класс. Также проблема в xml-конфигурации: в ней вы указываете имя класса `main.Hello`, а в вашей программе этот класс лежит в пакете `Spring` (соответственно его имя - `Spring.Hello`). Так как вы утверждаете что

> В тестовом уроке об этом не слова.

я рекомендую выбросить этот тестовый урок на помойку и почитать что-нибудь более близкое к реальности, например:

- [Примеры и уроки на официальном сайте проекта](http://projects.spring.io/spring-framework/)
- [Они же, переведённые на русский](http://spring-projects.ru/)
- [Простенький Hello World](http://www.mkyong.com/spring/quick-start-maven-spring-example/) (урок относится к версии 2.x, но всё описанное там актуально и для более поздних версий)
- Замечательная книга Крейга Уоллса [Spring в действии](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/19954704/)